# Angular 4/5 router issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I am starting on a new project and I am trying to get all my pages moving aroud correctly yet every time I try to switch pages I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): EmptyError: no elements in sequence
>
> AppMoule.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
    
    
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
    import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
    import { BlogComponent } from './components/blog/blog.component';
    import { PortfolioComponent } from './components/portfolio/portfolio.component';
    import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact/contact.component';
    import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
    
    
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
      { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
      { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        BlogComponent,
        PortfolioComponent,
        ContactComponent,
        NavbarComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

> AppComponent.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<!--<app-footer></app-footer>-->
```

Just started this project and I am not eve using promises but if I try going from the home page to any other page then I get that error stated earlier. Any help would be appreciated!

Just in case:

> navbarComponent.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse mb-4">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Crafty Tech</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="/about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" routerLink="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },`

Comment: if you want to load the homeComponent for every one of the routes, which it seems to do, you need to add the routes as children.

Comment: Try changing  each link in form [routerLink]="['/about']" 
e.g. `<li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>` for home.

Comment: AppMoule? not AppModule?

Comment: I just misspelled app module that was an oversight.